# Giant Atx MTB rear wheel quick release not opening

Tags: mountain-bike, rear-wheel, quick-release

Bike is a Giant Atx 27.5 2016

I have to replace the tube on the back wheel but the quick release lever is too tight and will not pull open, is there a trick to loosen it?

Comment: More leverage - use a short pipe over the handle to pry it up.  Try closing it a fraction more too - that might help break the hold.   A QR should be tight enough to mark your hand as you close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pipe that you wrap around the QR to have a bigger lever, but be careful not to apply to much force (because you will have a lot more)!
If the lever is stuck against the frame (so you cannot place your fingers around), try with a screwdriver first to pry it open(but put a cloth or something to prevent damage on the frame).

Perhaps the axle of the QR is rusty? -> WD40 then :)

Comment: I just bought the bike two weeks ago, so I don't think the axle is rusty, any other advice?

Comment: If you just bought it, take it back to the shop. Using tools to open the QR means you void the warranty. Take it back, let them decide what to tell. you.